# Existence of a square root of a given line bundle via Chern class?

Tags: vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

I come across a statement like

> Let $L$ be a complex line bundle on a manifold. $c_1(L)=0$ mod $2$ if and only if there exists a line bundle $K$ such that $L\cong K^{\otimes 2}$.

How can one prove this statement? Does one need some further assumption?

Comment: Complex line bundles are classified by the first Chern classes. If the class of a bundle is twice the class of another, then the former bundle is the square of the latter.

Comment: I think that complex line bundles are classified by elements in $H^1(M,\mathcal{O}^{\times})$ and the first Chern class is the image of the boundary map of the exponential exact sequence $0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}^{\times} \rightarrow 0$. I am not sure if this map is injective and first Chern classes really classifies complex line bundles.

Comment: In the smooth categry, $\mathcal O$ is a fine sheaf, so it is acyclic for cohomology.

Comment: You are right. I usually work in algebraic or holomorphic category and am being confused. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mariano's comment has essentially answered the question, but I'll go ahead and flesh it out.

On any manifold $X$, there is an isomorphism of groups
$$\mathrm{Pic}(X) \xrightarrow{~\cong~} H^2(X; \mathbb{Z}),$$
$$L \mapsto c_1(L).$$
Now if
$$c_1(L) \equiv 0 \pmod 2,$$
then there is some element $a \in H^2(X; \mathbb{Z})$ such that
$$c_1(L) = 2a.$$
The above isomorphism tells us that there exists a complex line bundle $K \in \mathrm{Pic}(X)$ such that $c_1(K) = a$ and
$$K \otimes K \mapsto 2a = c_1(L).$$
Then
$$K \otimes K \cong L,$$
so that $K$ is a square root of $L$.

For a proof of the above isomorphism, see for example Proposition 3.10 in Allen Hatcher's unfinished book *[Vector Bundles and $K$-Theory](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/VBKT/VBpage.html)*.

Comment: Do you mean $K\otimes K \mapsto 2a$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Yes, thanks for noticing the typo.